# Xcode and Generate Debug Symbols

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Which setting in Project Settings page needs to be set in order for Xcode to generate debug symbols for a project?

If I set 'Generate Profiling Code" to checked, as soon as I try to build, I get the error,

> cc1obj: error: unrecognised debug
>   output level "-full"

If not, the other way to do this I thought was by setting the 'OTHER_CFLAGS' value to '-g' but it also yields the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Under your compiler's settings group ("i.e. GCC 4.2 - Code Generation") there's a setting called "Generate Debug Symbols".

You can get an overview of probably all debug-related settings just by typing "debug" in the search box.

Comment: Working with a copy of a release profile, searching for 'debug' yields: 'Debug Information Format', 'Strip Debug Symbols During Copy',  'Dead Code Stripping'. No 'Generate Debug Symbols' option found in either debug or release configuration.